# Redirecting admin user before creating an order in adminpanel issue M1

Tags: magento-1, event-observer, sales-order

I have a custom condition for customers . If that condition is satisfied I would like make a redirect with a message that 'the order cannot be created'.

I used the `sales_order_place_before` event to check my condition and then make the redirect. My problem is that even if my condition is satisfied the order is still created and my message is displayed. How can I prevent the order from being saved ?

This my observer code:

```
        $blacklist = Mage::getModel('mynamespace_mymodule/customers')->getCollection()
                   ->addFieldToFilter('email', $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getCustomerEmail());
        if ((int)$blacklist->getSize() === 1){
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addWarning('Cannot create the order! The customer is added to the blacklist!');
            Mage::app()->getResponse() ->setRedirect('adminhtml/sales_order_create/')->sendResponse();
            return;
        }
```

Comment: try to use throw Exception instead of redirect

Comment: @MineshPatel , its working , but I am redirected to part when you have to select the store, I would like to be redirected to the sales order grid. Is that possible ?

Comment: yes possible but not only from observer.

Comment: `1. create you custom exception model. `  
`2. throw your exception from observer.`  
`3. catch your exception from controller file and redirect from there.`

Comment: without above step Magento cannot rollback all DB transaction which are initiated using begin transaction.

Comment: @MineshPatel and do you know if there is another event or smth ? to used that  instead.

Comment: yes controller pre dispatch event can work for you. you need to identity controller and action in that.check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25862861/5336832)